# Need to know FTP files transferred

Tags: windows, ftp, iis

0

We have an IIS FTP setup, i see the logs are in "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\FTPSVC2" But from these logs how can we know what files were transferred? is there a possibility to get the file name in the logs for FTP sites? Also there are no logs collected for last two days, how do we know the reason for no logs? please can someone advise

tried to check the logs from C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\FTPSVC2 but seems like there are no files details in these logs, i wanted to know if there is a way to capture the files name that are being transferred

Comment: Not within IIS, but this should be easy to correlate with file system auditing.